# Matriz em alocação dinâmica com falha na execução

Tags: c, matriz, programação-dinâmica

Olá!

O código a seguir compilou, mas apresenta erro na execução:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct 
{
    char *nome;
    int valor;
    int peso;
} objeto;

objeto obj[] = {
    {"map",      10,   2},
    {"compass",   7,   1},
    {"water",    25,   6},
    {"tin",      24,   5},
};

 // max{ f(Xn-1, W-Pn) + Vn , f(Xn-1, W) }    

int solver(objeto *obj, int n, int capac )
{
    int i, j, taDentro, taFora;
    int **matriz = (int **) calloc(n+1, sizeof(int *));

    matriz[0] = (int *) calloc(capac+1, sizeof(int)); 
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) 
    {
        matriz[i] = (int *) calloc(capac+1, sizeof(int));

        for (j=1; j<=capac; j++)
        {
            taFora = matriz[i-1][j]; //coloca o item anterior?
            if (obj[i-1].peso > matriz[i][j]) matriz[i][j] = taFora;
            // -1 pq os itens em 'matriz' comecam em 1 
            else
            {
              taDentro = matriz[i-1][ j-obj[i].peso ] + obj[i].valor;
              if (taDentro > taFora) matriz[i][j] = taDentro;
              else                   matriz[i][j] = taFora;
            }
        }
    }
    int resultado;
    resultado = matriz[i][j];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) free(matriz[i]);
    free(matriz);
    return resultado;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    int capac = 7;
    int resultado;
    resultado = solver(obj, n, capac);
    printf("%d\n", resultado);
}
```

A janela do windows mostra essa informação:

*Nome do Evento de Problema:    APPCRASH*

Não sei se estou tentando gravar ou ler informação em espaço errado, ou se estou usando os ponteiros de forma errada. Ou as duas coisas.

Senhores, poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: O resltado é um número inteiro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo que você use o GDB para depurar o seu programa, caso você não consiga resolver o problema.

De acordo com o depurador, a falha de segmentação ocorre na seguinte linha:

```
resultado = matriz[i][j];
```

**Valores das variáveis após a falha de segmentação:**

i = 4

j = 8

capac = 7

n = 3

O que podemos notar é que:

O seguinte laço:

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
```

A variável i começa em 1, o laço gira enquanto i for menor ou igual a 3 (valor de n), até aí tudo bem, porém atente-se a condição **i<=n**, esta condição apenas será falsa quando i for maior do que n, ou seja, quando possuir o valor 4.

Na seguinte linha: `int **matriz = (int **) calloc(n+1, sizeof(int *));` você reserva n+1 espaços para a sua matriz, no caso, 3+1 = 4, como endereçamento de vetores começa em 0, posições legais para o seu vetor seria entre 0 a 3 (4 posições), para corrigir esta falha, basta decrementar o valor de i pois o seu vetor não possui a linha 4.

Note que a variável j também sofre deste mesmo problema.

**Você possui duas opções:**

```
int resultado;
resultado = matriz[--i][--j]; // --i é diferente de i--
```

**Ou**

```
i--;
j--;
int resultado;
resultado = matriz[i][j];
```

**Recomendo que leia:**

[Tutorial GDB (gnu debugger)](http://www.lrc.ic.unicamp.br/~luciano/courses/mc202-2s2009/tutorial_gdb.txt)

[O que é falha de segmentação](https://vinipsmaker.wordpress.com/2013/12/20/meu-erro-favorito-de-cc-falha-de-segmentacao/)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Eu corrigi os erros e o programa agora funciona. As dicas  sobre o GBD e o que é falha de segmentação foram muito bem recebidas. É a minha segunda pergunda aqui no StackOverflow, e estou realmente impressionado com a atenção que seus membros prestam.

Comment: Não se esqueça de verificar o valor da variável após o laço, este problema estava muito mascarado, tudo parecia funcionar perfeitamente. Para evitar confusões, prefira laços com o sinal de "menor" e "maior" ou "diferente" ao invés de "menor e igual" ou "maior e igual". a Comunidade StackOverflow é excelente, por este motivo peço para não se esquecer de marcar uma questão como correta, desta maneira outras pessoas poderão se beneficiar da resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema esteja nesta linha:

```
resultado = matriz[i][j];
```

Pois neste momento o `i` será `n+1` e o `j` será `capac+1`, que são posições não alocadas.

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui resolvr o problema.